# What am I doing wrong in this split for excel rows loop?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, attributeerror, nonetype

I wrote this little code to split domains from lists of urls in excel workbook. But the problem is i can't get it to write in the actual workbookt or even create a new workbook with the domains.

```
#looping it
for i in range(2, 200):
print((sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value).split('http://')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1])

#but by this i have to go copy paste the results in the excel sheet
#so i tried this replace value method but it keeps showing attribute error

for x in range(2, 258):
    sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value = sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value.split('http://')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 2, in <module>
    sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value = sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value.split('http://')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I want this loop go through the list and split the url(htts://www.example.com/example-page/) to domain(example.com) and save it in the same sheet or a new sheet when i 
    use this

```
wb.save('domains_list')
#it saves the splitted domains automatically without me copy pasting it from idle to excel workbook.
```

Comment: Some of your cells don't contain any strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the comments, you have to manage the case where a cell is empty:

```
for i in range(2, 200):
    val = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    if val is None:
        continue   
    print(val.split('http://')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1])
```